# sed - how to refer to the outer match from within a block?

Tags: sed

For example:

I have a piece of sed as follows:

```
36   sed $'
37   /^waitForVisible/ {
38       s/this/& and that/
39     s/waitForVisible/expect/
40     s/)$/).to be_visible\\\n/
41   }
```

with line 38 replacing `&` with the word `this` (the match)

Can I do a similar thing for line 39 but in this case use the match found for the block back in line 37 (i.e. replacing `waitForVisible` with a special character(s)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  If you exchange 39 with 38, you can take advantage of the fact that an empty match expression means *repeat the last match*:

```
36   sed $'
37   /^waitForVisible/ {
39     s//expect/
38       s/this/& and that/
40     s/)$/).to be_visible\\\n/
41   }
```

Obviously, this could fail to be equivalent if lines 38 and 39 could make conflicting substitutions.